# Rename a resource in a RESTful way

Tags: rest

What is best practice for renaming a resource in a RESTful way?
Let's say my users can maintain named lists of things with the uri

```
http://example.org/users/{userName}/lists/{listName}
```

I want to give my users an API to rename a certain list. What is the preferred way?

I came up with the following so far:

- POST to to the list resource with the post-data "newname=..."
- PUT the list to the new URI and then DELETE the old URI

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First step is fine, but I suggest you not to delete old URI, because every link to that resource will be break.  instead return **HTTP Code 301 "Moved Permanently"**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301